# how to reference 3 functions while using struct

Tags: c++

//I want to use 3 functions here with 1 struct that one function do the input
 and one for calculation and the other one for out put but 
I don't know how to reference //the variables in functions rec2 and rec3. I want to do it without using pointer

```
struct rectangle {
    float length;
    float width;
    float area,perimeter;
}; 

rectangle rec1();
rectangle rec2();
rectangle rec3();

int main(){
    rectangle f;
    f = rec1(); 
    f=rec2();
    f = rec3(); 

    return 0;
}

rectangle rec1(){
    rectangle h;
    cout<<"insert the length: ";
    cin>>h.length;
    cout<<"\ninsert width: ";
    cin>>h.width;    
    return h;    
}

rectangle rec2(){
    rectangle z;
    z.area=z.length*z.width;
    z.perimeter=2*(z.length+z.width);
    return z;           
}

rectangle rec3(){
    rectangle x;
    cout<<"\narea is: "<<x.area<<endl<<"perimeter is: "<<x.perimeter<<endl;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Give the `rectangle` as a parameter to the functions?...

Comment: In function `rec2`, you are using un-initialized variables to determine the area.  If you did initialize the variables in your constructor, the `rec2` function always returns the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add methods to your `rectangle` struct.

```
struct rectangle
{
    float length, width, area, perimeter;
    void Input()
    {
       cout << "insert the length: ";
       cin >> length;
       cout << "\ninsert width: ";
       cin>> width;
    }
    void Process(); // etc
    void Output(); // etc
};

// Create a rectangle object and call it's methods
int main()
{
  rectangle r;
  r.Input();
  r.Process();
  r.Output()
}
```

The methods can now reference the *member variables* of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your design.
Place the input, process and output functions as methods inside the `rectangle` structure.

Placing the functions inside the structure allows them to access the data members.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you return a new `rectangle` and assign it to your `f` variable, you are overwriting all of `f`'s members, not just the ones you modified inside the function.  You need to change the functions to modify `f` directly instead.  You don't have to use a pointer for that, you can use a reference instead:

```
struct rectangle {
    float length;
    float width;
    float area, perimeter;
}; 

void rec1(rectangle&);
void rec2(rectangle&);
void rec3(rectangle&);

int main(){
    rectangle f;
    rec1(f); 
    rec2(f);
    rec3(f); 

    return 0;
}

void rec1(rectangle &r){
    cout << "insert the length: ";
    cin >> r.length;
    cout << endl << "insert width: ";
    cin >> r.width;    
}

void rec2(rectangle &r){
    r.area = r.length * r.width;
    r.perimeter = 2 * (r.length + r.width);
}

void rec3(rectangle &r){
    cout << endl << "area is: " << r.area << endl << "perimeter is: " << r.perimeter << endl;
}
```

But, this is C++ we are talking about, afterall.  Member methods are your friends :)

```
struct rectangle {
    float length;
    float width;
    float area, perimeter;

    void rec1();
    void rec2();
    void rec3();
}; 

void rectangle::rec1(){
    cout << "insert the length: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl << "insert width: ";
    cin >> width;    
}

void rectangle::rec2(){
    area = length * width;
    perimeter = 2 * (length + width);
}

void rectangle::rec3(){
    cout << endl << "area is: " << area << endl << "perimeter is: " << perimeter << endl;
}

int main(){
    rectangle f;
    f.rec1(); 
    f.rec2();
    f.rec3(); 

    return 0;
}
```